# Why is Python multiprocessing calling code that was not specified?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement multiprocessing to my webscraping project in order to scrape a list of 200 pages 10 at a time, rather than 1 at a time.

My issue is that while implementing the code, what should call a function on a list is causing a big glitch where it recalls input statements outside of the function that was called.

Here is the whole example script to show the problem:

```
#print statements to request necessary details to perform scrape
cleanURL = input("What is the URL? ")
pn = input("What is the product name? ")
condition = input("Is the product used or new? ").lower()
pages_available = input('How many pages of data do you want? ')

def scrape_page(URL):
    #variables for storing/cleaning data for mysql queries
    headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


#creates a list of 200 urls
url_list = []
for pages_unscraped in range(int(pages_available)+1):
    URL = cleanURL + str(pages_unscraped)
    if (pages_unscraped > 0):
        url_list.append(URL)

#supposed to call the scrape_page function on the entire url_list
if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Pool(10)
    p.map(scrape_page, url_list)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

The problem that is occurring is that it recalls the input statement 10 times rather than calling just the 'scrape_page' function on 10 urls out of the list at a time.

How can I stop the programming from causing this issue?

Comment: Where's the `scrape_page` function?

Comment: Its over 100 lines in the actual program but the editted version gives an example function to replicate the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all of your 'single-execution' code (like the `input` statements) either in the `if __name__=='__main__':` guard scope, or in a separate function that will be called from within that guard—guaranteeing only a single execution.

What Python does when it runs multiprocessing is ultimately running a new interpreter (*yes, there are some platform differences that can let you get away with it on fork-able systems, but for the sake of simplicity...*) with the Python script containing the function to be called and then calls that function. Anything on the global scope of that script will get executed before Python has the chance to call the intended function.